# Rails validation regex not working: invalid though input correct

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, validation

I am trying to validate kind of a datetime field with a regex. The regex is correct - I tested it on rubular - but Rails throws an error on the field: invalid.

In my model I have:

```
validates :ddate, presence: true, format: { with: /\A(\d\d\.){2}\d{4} \d\d:\d\d\z/ }
```

In my form I enter: `25.12.2015 20:15` and get the validation error: ddate is invalid

I tried to break it down and started with:

```
validates :ddate, presence: true, format: { with: /\A\d\d/ }
```

which worked as expected, then I tried:

```
validates :ddate, presence: true, format: { with: /\A\d\d\./ }
```

which did not work anymore.

Any hints, why this is not working?

I am using Rails 4.2.4 and Ruby 2.2.1p85.

Comment: What is the type of `ddate` in the database?

Comment: it's datetime, but I don't want to use a datetime_select in the form...

Comment: The regular expression matches against a string, it doesn't make sense to match against a date as the "format" of the date depends on the formatting settings you apply to it. Your validation doesn't make sense.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was exactly the point!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing a string, so make that instead:

```
attr_accessor :ddate_string

validates :ddate_string, presence: true, format: { with: /\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{4} \d{1,2}:\d{1,2}/ }

before_save :set_ddate

def set_ddate
  self.ddate = ddate_string
end
```

You can run regex validations only against strings.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I thought that - as in my form I use a text_field for ddate - the validation  runs against that string and only if it passes it goes to the DB as datetime. Lesson learned ;-)